# How to createe checkbox input for navigation menu added to categories left hand side

Tags: php, checkbox, checkboxlist

My Current navigation menu is without check box function. See below image.

[image without check box feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKsUG.png)

I want to create checkbox function for navigation menu. same as below image.

[Navigation with check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D480.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using Wordpress CMS, and a coupon site.

Comment: I'd add some code for what you have tried, before the code police show up yo.

Comment: Hello Justin, I do not see code in here you added.

Comment: hi, I meant for you to add code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry but did not try any new code yet on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_get_nav_menu_items() -> loop through menu objects -> build your HTML

Comment: Hello Denis, Can you help me with code, I am not code savy, and still a learner.